# AGRUPAR POR IDUSUARIO EN ELOCUENTE LARAVEL EXTRAYENDO TODAS LAS COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

TENGO ESTA CONSULTA EN MYSQL Y NECESITO PASARLA A ELOCUENTE
SELECT id,idusuario,idempresa,nombreconem,telefonoconem,emailconem,motivoconem,statusconem, created_at, updated_at, senderid, recipientid FROM contactaempresa WHERE recipientid=27 GROUP BY idusuario

pero no sé cómo agregar GROUPBY en elocuente  AQUI TRAIGO TODOS LOS DATOS

$messages = Contactoempresa::where('recipientid', $user->id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

intente algo así pero no funciona  AQUI LOS QUIERO AGRUPAR

$messages =  Contactoempresa::where('recipientid', $user->id)->where('statusconem', 'A')->with('users')->Groupby('idusuario')->get();

Manda este error
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'concreto.contactaempresa.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `contactaempresa` where `recipientid` = 27 and `statusconem` = A group by `idusuario`)
ALGUNA IDEA?

Comment: Se trata de obtener datos agrpados por id ya edite la pregunta

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'concreto.contactaempresa.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `contactaempresa` where `recipientid` = 27 and `statusconem` = A group by `idusuario`)

Comment: claro lo entiendo pero¿ como se pasa a elocuente en LARAVEL esa es la duda?

Comment: me ahorre el problema cree un procedimiento almacenado y solo mande a llamar gracias